# Iteration over rows (Two Loops) Automation Pandas DataFrame

Tags: loops, for-loop, iteration

I have the following iteration  (for loop) for every row depending on the Indicator 'H' and 'G' in df1. Creates a new column with the product of the selected indicators. Now i would like that this is automatically down for all indicators (if i have more than 'H' and'G'). Unfortuntely I am struggling to put it in a dictionary.

Can anyone help with this? Thank you and have an ecellent week.

```
   df1 =pd.DataFrame({'Country':['Armenia','Azerbaidjan','Belarus','Armenia','Azerbaidjan','Belarus'],\
                 'Indictaor':['G','G','G','H', 'H', 'H'],'2005':[3,4,5,6,7,4],'2006':[6,3,1,3,5,6]})

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2005,2006,2005,2006],
                        'Country1':['Armenia','Armenia','Azerbaidjan','Azerbaidjan'],
                        'Country2': ['Belarus','Belarus','Belarus','Belarus']})

    df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2005,2006,2005,2006],                   
                        'Country2': ['Belarus','Belarus','Belarus','Belarus'],
                        'Country1':['Armenia','Armenia','Azerbaidjan','Azerbaidjan'],
                         'IndictaorGProduct':[15,6,35,5],
                          'IndictaorHProduct':[24,18,28,30]})

    gprod = []
    hprod =[]

for row in df4.iterrows() :
        c1 = row[1][2]
        c2 = row[1][1]
        yr = str(row[1][0])
        g1 = df1.loc[(df1['Country']==c1)&(df1['Indictaor']=='G')]
        g1val = g1[yr].values[0]
        g2 = df1.loc[(df1['Country']==c2)&(df1['Indictaor']=='G')]
        g2val = g2[yr].values[0]
        print(g1val, g2val, g1val*g2val)
        gprod.append(g1val*g2val)
    df4['GProduct'] = gprod

for row in df4.iterrows() :
        c1 = row[1][2]
        c2 = row[1][1]
        yr = str(row[1][0])
        g1 = df1.loc[(df1['Country']==c1)&(df1['Indictaor']=='H')]
        g1val = g1[yr].values[0]
        g2 = df1.loc[(df1['Country']==c2)&(df1['Indictaor']=='H')]
        g2val = g2[yr].values[0]
        print(g1val, g2val, g1val*g2val)
        gprod.append(g1val*g2val)
    df4['HProduct'] = hprod
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where you get the Indicators from. Do you decide on them or do you get them from the column?

In case you get them from the respective column you could use the column to get a list with unique values from the column. Then you can loop over the values in a second loop. But note that, depending on your data size, this might not be very efficient.

However here is what you could do:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Armenia', 'Azerbaidjan', 'Belarus', 'Armenia', 'Azerbaidjan', 'Belarus'], \
                    'Indictaor': ['G', 'G', 'G', 'H', 'H', 'H'], '2005': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4],
                    '2006': [6, 3, 1, 3, 5, 6]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2005, 2006, 2005, 2006],
                    'Country1': ['Armenia', 'Armenia', 'Azerbaidjan', 'Azerbaidjan'],
                    'Country2': ['Belarus', 'Belarus', 'Belarus', 'Belarus']})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2005, 2006, 2005, 2006],
                    'Country2': ['Belarus', 'Belarus', 'Belarus', 'Belarus'],
                    'Country1': ['Armenia', 'Armenia', 'Azerbaidjan', 'Azerbaidjan'],
                    'IndictaorGProduct': [15, 6, 35, 5],
                    'IndictaorHProduct': [24, 18, 28, 30]})

cols = ['Year', 'Country2', 'Country1']
df4 = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
df4['Year'] = df2['Year']
df4['Country1'] = df2['Country1']
df4['Country2'] = df2['Country2']




indicators = df1["Indictaor"].unique() # get all the unique indicators from the indicators column, you could also manually have alist with the indicators you want to loop over

for i in indicators:
    prod = []
    for row in df4.iterrows():
        c1 = row[1][2]
        c2 = row[1][1]
        yr = str(row[1][0])
        g1 = df1.loc[(df1['Country'] == c1) & (df1['Indictaor'] == i)] # compare to the indicator in the list
        g1val = g1[yr].values[0]
        g2 = df1.loc[(df1['Country'] == c2) & (df1['Indictaor'] == i)]
        g2val = g2[yr].values[0]
        print(g1val, g2val, g1val * g2val)
        prod.append(g1val * g2val)
    colname = "".join([i,"Product"])
    df4[colname] = prod

print("Done")
```

Comment: This is great! Unforfuntely applied to my dataset I get the error. Length of values does not match length of index (Line df4[colname] = prod.

Comment: That means that somehow the length of prod is not matching the number of rows of your dataframe. You could check before if they have the same length: if (len(prod) == df4.shape[0]): df4[colname] = prod and maye in the else print a message when it did not work. But without your data its impossible to know whats going on. Do you use my exact code? you have to make sure that you overwrite 'prod' after each indicator!

Comment: Thankl you ver ymuch I solved it. Excellent work for me!